# Testing a RESTFull post request that expects MediaType_Application

Tags: java, json, jackson, rest-assured

I get an illegal state exception because it cannot serialize the object to json as there is no json serializer in the classpath.

This is my test method.

```
    @Test
    public void testAddUser() {
    User user = new User(1, "hhhh", "1234", "bbbb", "bbbbb");           

    given()
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .body(user)
    .expect()
    .statusCode(200) 
    .log().ifError()
    .when()
    .post("/rest/user/add");
}
```

This is the jackson dependencies I have added which I assume have added jackson to the classpath. Also I added a jax-rs jackson jar to the build path as well but still recieving that error.

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

Is there something I am completely missing out on here?

I have also checked the WEB-INF/lib and the JARS are in there aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly oversight on my part. As i am deploying the test in a web archive i should have included it in that actual archive like below.

```
libs = Maven.resolver().resolve("org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core- 
asl:1.9.13")               
.withTransitivity().as(File.class);
archive.addAsLibraries(libs);
```